# 3rd party Slimee DatePicker: how to handle parse error?

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

I need to use the mentioned 3rd party datepicker and it throws an exception when an invalid date it entered. The author only exposes one event, which is fired when a successful parse takes place. How, in ASP.NET could I catch this error and do something about it, like set a label's text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take here, personally I would replace the default event handler for the TextChanged event via inheritance.

The code assigns one via during the setup and unfortunately textbox is a private member

```
textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedDateChanged);
```

which is declared as

```
protected virtual void OnSelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So we can inherit SlimeeLibrary.DatePicker

```
public class EnhancedDatePicker : SlimeeLibrary.DatePicker
```

and then override the EventHandler raising a new parse error event.

public event EventHandler OnDateParseError;

```
protected override void OnSelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnSelectedDateChanged(sender, e);
    }
    catch (FormatException fe)
    {            
        OnDateParseError(sender, e);
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.  I haven't checked it but have examined the code for slimees control, but don't want to setup a code project account to download it sorry.  You'll obviously need to change your ASP.NET usercontrol references to use the new class.